# Rails: s3_direct_upload - How do I save/use the data response?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, amazon-s3, coffeescript

I've searched all over SO for an answer, so I'm sure this hasn't been asked before. Please help me, o savior!

I'm trying to use the [s3_direct_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) gem to handle uploading files directly to S3, but I just don't know how to see/use/save the data that apparently is given back from the S3 server. I've read the README for s3_direct_upload a dozen times, and it gives some example snippets of JS code but doesn't tell me where that code should go.

I have worked through the first part of the README and set up AWS config and the simple jQuery

```
jQuery ->
  $("#s3-uploader").S3Uploader()
```

In my CoffeeScript (which is included in the asset pipeline correctly).

I have this in my view:

```
<%= s3_uploader_form callback_url: work_path, callback_param: "work[url]", class: "s3-uploader" do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: false %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for(@work) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name, "Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.label :category, "Category" %>
    <%= f.text_field :category %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Upload", id: "btn-upload-work", class: "btn btn-large btn-warning btn-upload" %>

<% end %>
```

I want the user to upload a `work` and fill in some fields. When the user clicks the `"Upload"` button, a new `work` should be created with attribute `:url` equal to the url of the file uploaded, as well as the `:name` and `:category` attributes equal to the text inputted by the user. Then the page should redirect to the `show` page of the submitted work. The README gives this example:

```
$('#myS3Uploader').bind "s3_upload_complete", (e, content) ->
  $('#someHiddenField').val(content.url)
```

But I have no idea where to put this bit of code.

This is my controller: (I know the `create` action needs changes, but I don't know exactly what. I've experimented for several hours with `respond_to` to no avail.)

```
def show
    @work = Work.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @work = Work.new
end

def create
    @work = current_user.works.new(work_params)
    if @work.save
        flash[:success] = "Work successfully submitted!"
        redirect_to @work
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

    def work_params
        params.require(:work).permit(:name, :category, :url)            
    end
```

Even after reading the README a dozen times, I still don't understand what `callback_url` really is, what `callback_param` is, and how to work with them. Even worse, loading this view gives an error - Rails doesn't like the `callback_url: work_path` portion. I had to change that to `work_path(@work)` to have it load, but I'm not sure if that's right (since I don't understand `callback_url`).

From the questions everyone else has asked about s3_direct_upload, it seems that they already know how to use it (the questions are just smaller details). So I'm lost because I can't even get it to work in the first place. I'm a bit new to web frontends, so please bear with me and explain this to me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I still don't understand what callback_url really is,

`callback_url` is the path that it would post to via AJAX after the gem finishes uploading the file to s3. So `work_path(@work)` should be ok.

> $('#myS3Uploader').bind "s3_upload_complete", (e, content) ->
> $('#someHiddenField').val(content.url)
>
> But I have no idea where to put this bit of code.

You can place the above code in the same coffeescript file where you put `$("#s3-uploader").S3Uploader()`.  Replace `$('#someHiddenField').val(content.url)` with `alert(content.url)`. This way if the upload is successful you will get an alert message.

Also paste the following code in the same coffeescript file

```
$('#myS3Uploader').bind "s3_upload_failed", (e, content) ->
  alert("#{content.filename} failed to upload : #{content.error_thrown}")
```

The above code would show an alert if there was an error.

If you do not see any of the two after submitting the file, then there is some other issue. I highly recommend using [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/). It is really helpful in debugging client side javascript functions. In firebug net panel you can see if the gem is making a call to the s3 server or not. It will also show any javascript errors in the console panel.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I see that the file isn't being uploaded at all after I put in a file. What might be stopping the file from being uploaded?

Comment: do you get any alerts after putting in the above codes? If not look at the firebug console for errors.

Comment: I realized that the form code should have "s3-uploader" as the id instead of class. The file now uploads fine, but I don't get any alerts. This is very weird. (Where would I see the alerts?)

Comment: one step done, now look at your rails server console and see if it gets request after the upload is done.

Comment: It gets the request. Parameters: {"url"=> ..., "filepath"=> ..., ..., "work"=>{"url"=>"..."}}.  A `work` is created and inserted into `ActiveRecord` with only the `:url` attribute, but that's not what I want. I just want the be able to access all the parameters so I save a `work` along with the other text fields. (I still don't see any alerts.)

Comment: you will need to write some js to do that, serach for `additional_data:` in the gem read me, that gives an option to pass additional params but you need to write js to fetch those from the form into js. Try it and if it does not work ask another question with your attempted code and errors if any

Comment: It turned out to be that the .coffee file wasn't indented properly; I have the general idea of what I want working now. I deleted the callback_url and callback_param because I didn't want the work to be saved immediately. I used s3_upload_complete event to insert the URL into a hidden field on the form. Thanks a ton for your help!